# Android creating preroll activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-webview

Hi I'm a new in Android development. But I need to do task with next order of actions:

- 1. In application click button "Show video"
- 2. Show Ad from mopub like(preroll)
- 3. Show webview with video
- 4. In the video click on button and show midroll (ad from mopub)

I almost did it but I'm not sure that I'm using correct approach for this, and I have next issues:

- If there opened video (webview) activity, and I collapse application, and after that I expand it, it close activity with video
  (webview) and returns to start activity of application.
- When I open midroll from the video (webiew) activity, that was opened from start activity of application, and close this midroll
  after, it close also and video activity and return me to application
  start activity (but I need to stay on video activity(this is kind of middle
  activity between application start activity and midroll) after
  preroll closed).

Here how I start this chain of actions (Class of the application):

```
public void showVeedi(View view) {
    final Context context = this;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AdVeediActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("GAME_ID", 3);
    intent.putExtra("GAME_LEVEL", getLevel());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here the part of class AdVeediActivity class with activity with ad(I use it for preroll and midroll):

```
private MoPubInterstitial mInterstitial;
private AQuery aq;
private String vimeoUrl = "http://www.veedi.com/mobile/android/server/Feed.php?id=";
private String orientation = "portrait";
private String mopubId = "";
private boolean isInitialized = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad_veedi);

    aq = new AQuery(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    vimeoUrl += extras.getInt("GAME_ID");
    final Context context = this;
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

    if (extras.getBoolean("IS_PLAYER_EXIST") != true) {
        aq.ajax(vimeoUrl, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {
                try {
                    orientation = json.getString("orientation");
                    mopubId = json.getJSONObject("adUnits").getString("landscape");
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
                    mInterstitial = new MoPubInterstitial((Activity) context, mopubId);
                    mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener((MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener) context);
                    mInterstitial.load();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        mInterstitial = new MoPubInterstitial(AdVeediActivity.this, extras.getString("MOPUB_ID"));
        mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener((MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener) context);
        mInterstitial.load();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(

) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras.getBoolean("IS_PLAYER_EXIST") != true) {
            final Context context = this;
//------------ Here I call activity with webview with video inside 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainVeediActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("GAME_LEVEL", extras.getInt("GAME_LEVEL"));
            intent.putExtra("GAME_ID", extras.getInt("GAME_ID"));
            intent.putExtra("MOPUB_ID", mopubId);
            intent.putExtra("ORIENTATION", orientation);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {

        }
        mInterstitial.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
    if (moPubInterstitial.isReady()) {
        mInterstitial.show();
        isInitialized = false;
    } else {
        // Other code
    }
}
```

And here class with video (webview) MainVeediActivity, that also ran previous class as midrool when user clcick button inside it

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_veedi);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_veedi);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "jsinterface");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.veedi.com/mobile/player/" + extras.getInt("GAME_ID") + "/" + (extras.getInt("GAME_LEVEL") - 1) + ".html");

}

final Context context = this;
final class JavaScriptInterface {
    JavaScriptInterface () { }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showMidroll() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AdVeediActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("IS_PLAYER_EXIST", true);
        intent.putExtra("MOPUB_ID", extras.getString("MOPUB_ID"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void closePlayer() {
        ((MainVeediActivity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

Can you help with my questions or may be with approach how to do it. Thanks.